# Why does Drop Box not work after 10.8 upgrade?

Tags: macos, smb

**Setup:** I got SMB shares on my old-old Mac Mini (running 10.5). I have Drop Box folder/directory with Write-only permission - it is used to be called "Dropbox". Recently I upgraded my laptop (MacBook) from 10.6 to 10.8. It was clean install - meaning format drive, install new OS.

**Issue:** Running 10.6 on my laptop, "Dropbox" use to work great - no issue whatsoever. Used it for over 5 years. However once I got 10.8, I can't seem to write to the remote (Mac Mini) SMB Write-only folder.

**Scenario:** Drag a file to "Dropbox" folder. Finder shows active window of copying a file. Once the transfer is done, I look under the folder (from a server side via VNC) and there are no file's.

I am certain the issue is with my laptop running 10.8, not a Mini. However I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Try creating a new user account, and see if you are able to write to that user's dropbox. That should help narrow the problem down a bit.

Comment: Additional information: Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I was looking at it and I can't see pattern. I'll try to create new account, but it doesn't look like it matters.

Comment: I can assure you, Dropbox is running on thousands of Macs running 10.8 - so you might either have some odd setting or more likely, you just need to go through dropbox support to troubleshoot dropbox in general. Are you looking for someone to point the way to the dropbox article on troubleshooting or willing to wait for more guesses as to what's wrong with your setup?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest it sounds like it could be a bug in DropBox, and you should contact them to find a solution (and please post the solution here if they give you one).

Why do you have the DropBox folder on the server? Why not have a dropbox folder on the server and a completely separate one on your notebook?

Perhaps it's not what you want, but it seems like that should work perfectly. DropBox usually sends files across to the other machine within a few seconds.

Comment: I don't think the question refers to the syncing software and cloud service DropBox, but rather to the shared folder called "Drop Box" included in a standard OS X user account.

Comment: It sounds like he has a DropBox on his mac mini, which he modifies via filesharing on his notebook, and sometimes the dropbox daemon fails to see that files have changed and sync's them up. Or maybe dropbox updates a file and the filesharing service fails to notify the notebook that it needs to flush it's cache of the file (btw: I am using dropbox on OS X 10.8 with no problems - but I don't have any weird server/client model like @Melr has)

Comment: "Drop Box" is use to be an idea ( before DropBox software and had nothing to do with it ) that implied that there is a shared folder (via SMB or other protocol ) on a remote machine and client can only write to it, but not read or over-write. Essentially folder only had write-only permission on network shared resource. 

Here I got something from console, I get it when file doesn't copy: 

Locum[7294]: Connection with distnoted server was invalidated

Answer (score 0):

A clean install of Mountain Lion means all your settings and preferences have been reset.

Please double check your *Sharing* settings under *System Preferences*.

Comment: @Melr installed 10.8 on the client, not on the server with the "Drop Box" folder.

Comment: There are no Sharing setting on mountain lion, I use it on my laptop. Only mac mini with 10.5 has shares.